# inbox.js in cs50w mail project not working

Tags: cs50

I am doing cs50w project "mail". In the project python codes have already been implemented and we only need to work on javascript code. The javaScript code should be able to fetch data from the server when composing an email and when viewing a mailbox. when I send an email that I have composed I get nothing and url adds '/?' and I don't know why.

I have also tried to add print in my view function to check if my functions are being called but nothing prints in the terminal meaning may be fetch function isn't working. I haven't changed anything in the codes that came with the project other than inbox.js and adding print in views.py.

I have tried to debug with print and console.log but still nothing. I was expecting a message to be printed in my terminal if one of the view function is called but nothing, I also added console.log but nothing is being log to my console.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data using [CS50's documentation](https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2020/projects/3/mail/#:%7E:text=fetch(%27/emails%27%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20method%3A%20%27POST%27%2C%0A%20%20body%3A%20JSON.stringify(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20recipients%3A%20%27baz%40example.com%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20subject%3A%20%27Meeting%20time%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20body%3A%20%27How%20about%20we%20meet%20tomorrow%20at%203pm%3F%27%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D)%0A.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0A.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20//%20Print%20result%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(result)%3B%0A%7D)%3B). Make sure to only fetch it after the form is submitted.

To actually see any created emails (assuming `load_mailbox()` isn't yet fully functional), register your Django Models in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, Email

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Email)
```

Then execute `python3 manage.py createsuperuser` command in the terminal to create an admin account.

After rerunning the server, add "/admin" to the url to enter Django's admin interface, where all models are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this probem and i think it is because i am using microsoft Edge when i tried to do this in opera gx, i was easily able to send the email. For me even closing the browser did not help at all. Change the Browser